# CSS and wicked_pdf not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

I'm not sure what i'm missing, but my css doesn't seem to be working along side wicked_pdf. I have an image linked in my file, which works, but the styles are missing.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

**Controller**

```
format.pdf do
  render pdf: "day_report", 
  template: 'day/day_report',
  page_size: 'A4'
end
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "styles" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
```

**day_report.pdf.erb**

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag( 'logo.jpg', height: '100', width: '100') %>

<div class="page-header">
    Day Report
</div>
```

**styles.css**

```
.page-header {
  padding: 40px 0;
  background-color: red;
  text-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Try adding styles directly to your day_report.pdf.erb.

Comment: This works, but seems an odd way around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Create a different layout for pdf as below. e.g pdf.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 
  'reload' %>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "styles" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

**Change controller action as:**

```
format.pdf do
  layout:'pdf.html',
  render pdf: "day_report", 
  template: 'day/day_report',
  page_size: 'A4',
  encoding:"UTF-8"
end
```

**Change styles.css to styles.scss and add it assets.rb.**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(styles.scss)
```

Hope this will help.

Cheers

Comment: Right. Resolved. I was putting the stylesheet links in my application header when I needed to put them in the pdf layout. Cheers.

Comment: Adding .css file to assets.rb worked for me.

Comment: Don't you need the method `render` in front of all the options?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please rename `styles.css` to `styles.css.scss` and add this file to precomiple list `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(styles.css)` and try.

Comment: Do I put this in my development/production environment?

Comment: You can put in application.rb file

Comment: Thanks Prosenjit. Still having the same issue. Just won't recognise the styles.

Comment: What you could try is add the following `config.assets.precompile += ['styles.css']` in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

Comment: No luck with that either Kedarnag.

Comment: After adding it to `assets.rb`, did you `precompile` assets ?